# After overriding the Application.getClasses() by a custom MessageBodyReader, methods on resource classes cannot be invoked

Tags: jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

In a *RESTEasy* project running on *Wildfly* server, there is a resource class:

```
@Path("/company")
public class CompanyResource {
  @Inject
  CompanyService companyService;

  @PUT
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public void update(Company company) {
    companyService.update(company);
  }
}
```

Initially the REST API configuration class just `extends Application` without any extra `@override` on the existing methods of `Application` class. An http request, `http://localhost:8080/workcontext/company`, with `PUT` as the http request method could work, meaning the `CompanyResource.update()` can be invoked successfully when receiving the aforementioned http request.

However, I then tried to add a custom `MessageBodyReader<Company>`:

```
public class CompanyReader implements MessageBodyReader<Company> {

  @Override
  public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
    return true;
}

  @Override
  public Company readFrom(Class<Company> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream)
        throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    try(JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(entityStream)) {
        JsonObject companyJson = reader.readObject();
        Company company = new Company();
        company.setCompanyCode(companyJson.getString("companyCode"));
        company.setName(companyJson.getString("name"));
        company.setHeadquarter(Region.valueOf(companyJson.getString("headquarter")));
        return company;
    }
  }

}
```

In order to make this custom `MessageBodyReader<Company>` work, I registered this class by overriding the `Application.getClasses()`:

```
public class JaxRsConfiguration extends Application {
  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
      Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
      classes.add(CompanyReader.class);
      return classes;
  }
}
```

I expected that this `MessageBodyReader<Company>` could be invoked when sending the same http `PUT` request, but on the opposite the response is: `RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/workcontext/company`

**Question: How to make this custom MessageBodyReader work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should annotate you're `CompanyReader` with `@Provider`. In your application if you return any classes in `Application.getClasses()` or `Application.getSingletons()` then, per the [spec](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/3.0/jakarta-restful-ws-spec-3.0.html#servlet), those are the only classes allowed to be used in your application.

> If either getClasses or getSingletons returns a non-empty collection then only those classes or singletons returned MUST be included in the published JAX-RS application.